# Bibtex not giving the right numbers for the citations used

Tags: bibtex

I am going to try to just describe the problem and not post my code here to see if someone just knows the answer.

Basically I set up some references and I have something like [1] Author ... [2] Author etc. So the Author is the same but the years differ. When I say \cite{Author-2} (assuming this is the label for [2]) I keep getting [1].

In my file there are 5 citations under the same Author and the output PDF keeps putting the wrong citation like above: gives [1] if I label with [2]. Any ideas on why this could be? I can post my code, but it is long...

Comment: Please don't provide the FULL code. a MWE is what you need to post: https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-working-example-mwe-what-is-that

Comment: the number will be in order of reference or alphabetic order by author depending on the bibtex style, You may need to run bibtex, then pdflatex twice for all numbers to resolve. You can easily post a complete small example, no text of your document is needed apart from some `\cite`  and `bibliography` and you can then remove any packages not used in the example.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: I'm not quite sure I understand your problem (it would be best if you could post a *small*, but compilable example document that reproduces the issue with as little code as possible), but in general the *entry key* (`Author-2` or `Author-1` or whatever you use) does not control the sorting or numbering of your entries. So it is entirely possible that `Author-2` becomes "1" and `Author-1` becomes "2". Depending on your bibliography style, entry may be sorted by author-title-year, author-year-title, citation order, ....